# what exactly was needing clarification on this closed and deleted question?

Tags: discussion, data-visualization

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38819/what-is-a-good-clean-brief-big-picture-outline-of-all-the-types-of-regression

it's just asking for an outline (aka overview) since there isnt one on the entire Web

Comment: ok just to move the meta so i can find out and improve the question

Comment: I don't think it's a meta question - it's not about the site.

Comment: @PeterFlom, see this quote from the [FAQ](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask): "If your question is about the site itself, please don't ask it here. Visit our meta-discussion site where you can talk about things **like what questions are appropriate**, what tags should be used, suggest a feature, point out a bug, or generally discuss how Cross Validated - Stack Exchange works."

Comment: oh ok.. well i dont think anyone is in a rush, i mean that one mod sure wasnt, didnt even comment on and just quickly closed it -- i think we all have patience for a good answer to a necessary and important questions about stats, specially regression

Comment: @Macro Oh, my bad. You meant the current question, which is about why the other question was bad. Yeah, I guess that's a meta question. I thought you meant the original question

Comment: @Peter, yes I meant the current question, although it may be closed (rightfully so, IMO) as *too localized* on meta :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you mean this request to reopen your old questions?

> if some don't do something differently, then they can be arranged by
>   the conditions needed to use them
>
> question dervied from these:
>
> [How does regression analysis help one understand how the typical value of the dependent variable change?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35827/how-does-regression-analysis-help-one-understand-how-the-typical-value-of-the-de)
>   [Explain regression to 7 years old](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35824/explain-regression-to-7-years-old)
>
> these questions should be **kept** as they show what good answers are
>   apart from the merely decent, though unsufficient, ones (and they
>   didnt even have any werid math symbols in them! :) A golden +

Well, basically it contains 0 data science questions, which is below the established acceptable limit on this site (1).  Please consult our [FAQ](https://stats.stackexchange.com/faq) for information about what kinds of questions are acceptable here and how to ask them well.

Comment: @kittensatplay, it appears you're looking for the site to be something it's not. The established guidelines make sense for the purposes of this site - to form a repository of well thought out, **clearly formulated** questions and answers.

Comment: kittens, the site's moderators have received many flags today indicating that some of your comments have been rude and offensive. Personally, I believe I can see where you're coming from and I sympathize with your objectives: it appears you have some penetrating questions to ask and you seek cogent, simple, well-explained, thoughtful answers. Unfortunately your comments tend to be accusatory, like the one here: they attack people and suggest they are stupid or unlearned or worse. This is not constructive. The flagged comments will have to be removed and I trust you will change your tone.